# Add ADBannerView to the footer of UITableViewController doesn't appear 

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, xcode3.2

I have UITableViewController I want to add ADBannerView to its footer

so I added the framework iAd.framework , and tried the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    ADBannerView* adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;

    [self.tableView.tableFooterView addSubview:adView];
}
```

But it doesn't appear.

am I missing something or what

Best regards

Comment: Have you google it.You will find many of the sample codes related to iads.What the change you have to do is add your ADBannerView in table view instead of main view.

Comment: I did as in the exampels , what's wrong

Comment: thanks I solved the problem and updated my question with another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work. You'll have to implement the datasource method called [tableView:viewForFooterInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForFooterInSection%3a)  and return the adbanner view. You might also have to implement the delegate method [tableView:heightForFooterInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForFooterInSection%3a)

Comment: it worked but I need it to be at the bottom of the screen not at the end of the table data, also why it doesn't show any ads, any ideas

Comment: It should only show that test ad while your in development. you won't get live ads until you publish to the store.  To put the ad at the bottom of the screen, you'll have to shrink the size of your table view to make room at the bottom, then put it in your hierarchy with [self.view addSubview:adView]. You'll also need to use a regular UIViewController with a custom tableView property, because UITableViewController puts the table view full length.